# Reple.it - How can I import css and javascript with relative path

Tags: read-eval-print-loop

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUEdI.png)

This doesn't work. I can't import css, js and images.
Someone could help me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't post images, or links to images. You will need to post the code here, also your question does not describe the problem or describe what steps you have tried. Please read this and then edit your question appropriately: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use html/css/javascript template.
Relative path works there.